# timevalue("23:50")

Tags: excel, vba

This is just nuts.

I have a cell (in excel) in which I type "23:50" (without quotes). Next, with this cell selected, I go to the immediate window and type

msgbox activecell = timevalue("23:50")

..and it gives me "FALSE"!

I get TRUE for everything else, for eg with 23:49 or 23:51 (or any other time for that matter) in the cell and correspondingly in the code, but with 23:50 its breaking down for no reason.

This line is part of a bigger code, where this condition needs to be TRUE for the rest of it to execute. Using Excel 2007 on Win 7.

Comment: `timevalue(activecell.text)=timevalue("23:50")`

Comment: +1 but that should really be an answer. For details on why this problem occurs see http://stackoverflow.com/q/235409/53614

Comment: thanks barrowc for the insight as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test with this instead:

```
timevalue(activecell.text) = timevalue("23:50")
```

Likely your mismatch is due to the numeric equivalents not matching exactly:

```
      activecell.value = 0.99305555555555_5_
```

but

```
cdbl(timevalue("23:50"))=0.99305555555555_6_
```

Comment: Sir Tim Williams I would knight thee if I could.. ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Though I'm still annoyed why it would work for all the other times except for 23:50. But now I don't have to care.