# Comparison using Val() function in VB6 failing?

Tags: vba, vb6

```
Dim HHs As String
HHs = Mid("2345", 1, 2)

If Val(HHs) > 23 Then
"Log the Error that needs to be logged"
End If
```

The above code is failing in the validation .
This seems to be a very simple problem
Any idea why?

Comment: Where is `MMs` assignment???

Comment: `HHe` is not the same variable as `HHs` - **Always** use `Option Explicit`, and you'll avoid these errors 99 times out of 100.

Comment: `"Log the Error that needs to be logged"` is not a valid statement. Did you perhaps mean `Debug.Print "Log the Error that needs to be logged"` or maybe `'Log the Error that needs to be logged`?

Comment: Your edit still isn't naming the variables correctly and consistently. PLEASE use Option Explicit - you'll do yourself a favor! `Dim HHs As String`

Comment: I don't have any error using visual basic 6. Are you using VBA? What si your Office version?

Comment: After your edits which have invalidated most of the comments and some of the answers, I'm not seeing the problem. As [Pedro points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45933642/2344413), the left two characters of `2345` are `23`, which, when implicitly converted to a `Long`, are exactly equal to `23`. since `23 = 23` is `True`, you'll never drop into your `"Log error"` code. Therefore, you don't have a problem as your post stands at the moment. Please describe what behavior you're actually expecting.

Comment: If `2345` is supposed to represent a time and you're looking at the first two digits to determine if it is after 11pm, then use time formatting and don't try to deal with it as string information.

Comment: Val returns a double.  It you're using VBA you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235409/compare-double-in-vba-precision-problem

Comment: `Val()` is bad, m'kay?

Answer (score 0):

If `HHs` hasn't been declared (and you haven't used `Option Explicit`), or you haven't assigned a value to `HHs`, then `Val(HHs)` will always be `0`....

As such, `Val(HHs) > 23` will always be `False`.

It seems likely you made a typo, and meant to use `HHe`?

Comment: Hey yea ,That was a typing mistake. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected: the if condition is false since Val(HHs) is 23.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandTest_Click()
    Dim HHs As String
    HHs = Mid("2345", 1, 2)

    If Val(HHs) > 23 Then
        MsgBox "Log the Error that needs to be logged"
    End If
End Sub
```