# Log function in excel (vba) - not giving me the right answer

Tags: excel, vba

In this code snippet below, the value of temp_int2 is 1, makes no sense to me. --> log(1000) = 3, that is log of base 10, the log function is base 'e'.

im not sure if its the "INT" function which problematic but could someone please assist.

[image]

```
temp_int2 = Int(Log(1000) / Log(10)) - 1
    'temp_int2 = Int(Log(cap_dec) / Log(10)) - 1

    MsgBox ("Value of log functuon -->" & CStr(Log(cap_dec) / Log(10)) & "    value after log function " & CStr(temp_int2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the [Int function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions) use  the [cLng function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions). While `Int` will cut off decimals, `cLng` will round to a `Long`.

Example `Int` will cut off

```
Int(99.2) '= 99
Int(99.5) '= 99
Int(99.8) '= 99
```

but `cLng` will round

```
cLng(99.2) '= 99
cLng(99.5) '= 100
cLng(99.8) '= 100
```

since computers and calculators calculate numeric and not algebraic there is probably a precision issue in calculation and `Log(1000) / Log(10)` is not *exactly* an algebraic `3` but a numeric `3` that is something like `2.99999999999998` which `Int` will cut off to `2` but `cLng` will round to `3`.

Note that Excel is a numeric calculation program and values of type `Double` are not exact values. The decimals are (as with any standard calculator too) only calculated up to a defined precision.
So a `Double` type `3` is not a `3` but something very close to `3` like `2.99999999999998`. So the [Log function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/log-function) returns a `Double` and also a devision `Log(1000) / Log(10)` returns a `Double` and this is not *exactly* `3` but very close to `3`.

Note that this is not a bug but in the nature of numeric calculations which are never exact but only precise, while algebraic calculations can be exact.

---

The same problem occurs when comparing values of type `Double`:

```
If DoubleA = DoubleB Then 'might not work
```

Here you need to use something like

```
If (DoubleA - DoubleB) ^ 2 < (10^ - Digits)^2
```

where `Digits` is the number of digits that need to be the same. Example

```
DoubleA = 0.9999999999
DoubleB = 1.0000000001
```

then `Digits` needs to be `<= 9` to consider them as equal.

If you need to do that often then it comes handy to use a function for that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsDoubleValueTheSame(DoubleA As Double, DoubleB As Double, Optional Digits As Long = 12) As Boolean
    IsDoubleValueTheSame = (DoubleA - DoubleB) ^ 2 < (10 ^ -Digits) ^ 2
End Function
```

and call it like

```
Debug.Print IsDoubleValueTheSame(0.9999999999, 1.0000000001, 9)  'true
Debug.Print IsDoubleValueTheSame(0.9999999999, 1.0000000001, 10) 'false
```

---

So to come back to your initial example:

```
Debug.Print Log(1000) / Log(10) = 3 'false
Debug.Print IsDoubleValueTheSame(Log(1000) / Log(10), 3, 15) 'true
Debug.Print IsDoubleValueTheSame(Log(1000) / Log(10), 3, 16) 'false
```

which means `Log(1000) / Log(10)` is actually `3` precise up to `15` digits and the 16ᵗʰ digit is different.

Further information about this:

- [Numeric precision in Microsoft_Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) (Wikipedia)
- [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) (Microsoft documentation)
- [Compare double in VBA precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235409/compare-double-in-vba-precision-problem) (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Thank you, this is the most concise explanation I could have expected! Appreciate the details. I will try your recommendations and maybe tweek my other math knowing the above.

Comment: @Kabir you're welcome. Note I added another link in case you need to compare numbers of type `Double` you cannot do that with `If DoubleA = DoubleB` but `If (DoubleA - DoubleB)^2 < (10^-Digits)^2` where `Digits` is the number of digits you need for precision: [Compare double in VBA precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235409/compare-double-in-vba-precision-problem)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, you did an excellent job of answering this.  I was in the middle of it last night but ran out of time to complete it.